# I have a user that is unable to open xlsx file

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a user that is unable to open xlsx file. Our environment is Office 2007, Win 7. Everyone else can access the file except for her. And it doesn't matter what PC she tries to access the file from - it seems to be linked to her profile/login.

We have tried to delete the shortcut, recreate it, change the file extension, verified that the spreadsheet is opening with excel, remove and add her back to the member groups (that have access). I have tried to open the spreadsheet under a different user's name, and e-mailed that copy to her.

Now, even more interesting is that she can open all other .xlsx files. I'm at a loss as to what else to try here. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unable to open"? What happens when she tries? Nothing? An error?

Comment: Have you copied the Excel file and see if she can gain access to the copy? (By that I mean open, save as, different file name). When you say open other .xlsx files, do you refer to that same directory? Are the permissions on that file **identical** to the others she can open?

Comment: Are you saying you're trying to access a file over a network, or a short cut, or a file on her local profile. Sounds like the file itself has permissions. Change the permission to everyone to test it

Answer (score 0):

Right click to that xlsx file, click to `Properties`, select `Security` tab. Checking her user name is in `Group or user names` list or not. If not, click to `Edit` then add her user name to this list.